# How can I get Google App Script is to loop and not only pull from the first row

Tags: javascript, loops, google-apps-script, google-sheets

```
function buildReport() {
  var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Invalid Login MM Pull Internal");
  var ws2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Invalid Login External MM Pull External");

  var data = ws.getRange("A2:G" + ws.getLastRow()).getValues();
  var data2 = ws2.getRange("A2:G" + ws2.getLastRow()).getValues();
  let payload = buildAlert(data);
  let payload2 = buildAlert(data2)

  sendAlert(payload);
}

//buildAlert Fuction
function buildAlert(data) {
  var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Invalid Login MM Pull Internal");
  var data = ws.getRange("A2:G" + ws.getLastRow()).getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    if (data[i][5] !== "SLACK_SENT")
  var ofo = 1;
  var restaurant = 2;
  var name = 3;
  var email = 4;
  var sent = 5;
  let payload = {
    "blocks": [
      {
        "type": "section",
        "text": {
          "type": "mrkdwn",
          "text": ":bell: Invalid Creds :bell:"
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "divider"
      },
      {
        "type": "section",
        "text": {
          "type": "mrkdwn",
          "text": data[i][2] + " has invalid creds for " + data[i][1]
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "section",
        "text": {
          "type": "mrkdwn",
          "text": "Please contact have AE contact " + data[i][3] + " at " + data[i][4]
        }
      },
    ]
  };
  ws.getRange(2 + i,7).setValue("SLACK_SENT");
}
};
(function buildAlert(data2) {
  var ws2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Invalid Login External MM Pull External");
  var data2 = ws2.getRange("A2:G" + ws2.getLastRow()).getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i < data2.length; i++){
    if (data2[i][5] !== "SLACK_SENT")
  var ofo = 1;
  var restaurant = 2;
  var name = 3;
  var email = 4;
  var sent = 5;
  let payload = {
    "blocks": [
      {
        "type": "section",
        "text": {
          "type": "mrkdwn",
          "text": ":bell: Invalid Creds :bell:"
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "divider"
      },
      {
        "type": "section",
        "text": {
          "type": "mrkdwn",
          "text": data2[i][2] + " has invalid creds for " + data2[i][1]
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "section",
        "text": {
          "type": "mrkdwn",
          "text": "Please contact have AE contact " + data2[i][3] + " at " + data2[i][4]
        }
      },
    ]
  };
  ws2.getRange(2 + i,7).setValue("SLACK_SENT");
}
});
function sendAlert(payload) {
  const webhook = "https://hooks.slack.com/services/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";
  var options = {
    "method": "post", 
    "contentType": "application/json", 
    "muteHttpExceptions": true, 
    "payload": JSON.stringify(payload) 
  };
try {
    UrlFetchApp.fetch(webhook, options);
  } catch(e) {
    Logger.log(e);
  }
};
```

**Trying to send slack message from a google sheet but right now it is only pulling from the first row and it does not loop.
The only thing that loops is when I run the code it populates a cell marking it as SLACK_SENT. Feel free to ask me any questions or need to clarify anything. I am pulling from two spreadsheets and want to send slack for both sheets.

Comment: You should explain where exactly are you stuck, in other words what part of your code has the loop that isn't working as you expect. If you don't know how loops work in JavaScript start by reading [Loops and iteration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration)

Comment: I'm a bit confused why do you have 2 definition of `buildAlert()` and why is it that you call the function with parameter in `buildReport()` but at the same time you overwrite the data when you read the sheet values inside  `buildAlert()`? I want to follow-up @Ruben's query, please identify which row data is not being looped?

Answer (score 0):

```
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');//data sheet
const osh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');//output sheet
const [hA, ...vs] = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
let col = {};
let oA = [];//data desired
hA.forEach((h,i) => col[h] = i+1);
vs.forEach(r => {
  if(r[col['columntitle desired ']]  == "value desired") {
    oA.push(r);// push entire row
  }
});
osh.getRange(sh.getLastRow() + 1, 1, oA.length, oA[0].length).setValues(oA);
```

Comment: Can you explain? Where or what do I need to replace?

Comment: It's just an example of how to loop through data selecting the rows that you want based upon the value in column you want and then putting them into another sheet.  So it incorporates the use of a loop using the array forEach method.  How you wish to utilize it is up to you.